# returning local variable after callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api

I'm trying to write a method that returns an array, but the return value is empty. I think it's because it's happening before the local variable is set. I also think I looking at this totally wrong. Can anyone tell what would be the best pattern or practice to accomplish this? Code below.

```
// THIS IS MY JAVASCRIPT METHOD
this.getAllMediaTypes = function() {
    // MY LOCAL VARIABLE
    var allMediaArr = [];
    // METHOD I WROTE TO MAKE API CALL
    _thisObj.apiCall(_dataUrl + '/media.json?max=' + _thisObj.maxRecords +'&callback=?', function(){
        allMediaArr = _apiData.results;
    console.log(allMediaArr);//THIS RETURNS THE RIGHT DATA IN THE CONSOLE
    });
    // WHAT I WOULD LIKE RETURNED 
    return allMediaArr;// THIS IS RETURNING EMPTY       
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `apiCall` is asynchronous.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call This post resolved my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making an asynchronous call to the api. Make it synchronous.